# Running racket from the command line on windows

Tags: windows, command-line, racket

Is there a good way to run racket from the command line on windows 10? I know that PATH works, but the folder racket.exe is in contains other exe file that may cause conflicts (such as Uninstall.exe). Is there a way to do it other than adding the folder to path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always make a symlink for the Racket exe into a directory without the conflicting UNINSTALL file, and add that into your path.

You can find instructions on how to make a symlink at:

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Lets say you want to add it to `C:\Users\Me\bin`,  you would run:

```
mklink "C:\Program Files\Racket\Racket.exe" C:\Users\Me\bin
```

From there, you can [add `C:\Users\Me\bin` to your `PATH`](https://betanews.com/2015/11/23/windows-10-finally-adds-a-new-path-editor/), and run Racket from the command line.